# Handling exception that are managed in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

How should I handle those exceptions that I can't catch in the C# code behind... like for example I am facing failed email sending `system.Net.Sockets.SocketException` but I have no chance to handling the page codebhind.. where should I handle it?

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail1(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    string emailname="";
    try
    {
        TextBox textboxemail = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email");
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(textboxemail.Text);
        Guid userid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
        string verificationurl = "http://www.spiralsnet.com/Login.aspx?NewUserId=" + userid.ToString();
        e.Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        e.Message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("SpiralsWhirls@yahoo.com", "SpiralsNet");
        e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VU%>", verificationurl);
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
    {
        Membership.DeleteUser(emailname);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use `Try.. Catch` ?

Comment: Question updated.. the problem is that the error arise after the method is exited.

Comment: You can handle otherwise unhandled exceptions in the global.asax page with the Application_Error handler.

Comment: Thanks Tim.. yes this was the cause of the previous error too..

Comment: How do you want to _handle_ the exception? What could you possibly _do_ about it?

Comment: I think that's the wrong place to handle the exception. You're just preparing the `MailMessageEventArgs`, but you're not sending the email there. You should handle the exception at the place you're actually sending it. If you could post the StackTrace, it could be helpful.

Comment: The mail sending is managed by Membership ApI I think..

Comment: I want to cancel the user creation process in case of mail sending fails @JohnSaunders

Comment: In my case the mail is failing becuase I have not set up the smtp server on my local machine.. but I just want to know in case..